# ERROR when fetch JSON data within the Multi-array in React JS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-redux

I am having problem with fetching JSON data

the Error I'm getting is

```
  const list = this.state.images.map((image) =>
```

*Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.state.images.map is not a function*

this is [data API link](http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?%20q=ryan%20gosling&api_key=5500a486d12044849fe8ada1061c4d83&limit=5) , you can use postman to view the JSON data

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    //initiate props
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      images: []
    };
   this.articlesList = this.articlesList.bind(this);
  }

  //Component Lifecycle
  //what do we put in here ?
  componentWillMount() {

    //after data is fetched
    fetch('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=ryan+gosling&api_key=5500a486d12044849fe8ada1061c4d83&limit=5')
    .then(res => res.json()).then((data) => {
      // console.log('data', data)
      this.setState({images:data});

    })
  }

articlesList(){
  const list = this.state.images.map((image) =>
      <div className="col-md-6" key={image._id}>
         <Article url ={image.url}/>
      </div>
)

  return(list);
}
```

and I try to gain access to ***Images/Original/url*** in JSON file

Comment: what does the `data` look like

Comment: if you see this line of code     fetch('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=ryan+gosling&api_key=5500a486d12044849fe8ada1061c4d83&limit=5')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response coming back looks like this:

```
{ 
  "data": [],
  "pagination": {},
  "metadata": {}
}
```

So you'll need to set `images` to the `data` property that is in the JSON response. In the following snippet I changed your `data` variable to `resp` and then am accessing the `data` property.

```
//after data is fetched    
fetch('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=ryan+gosling&api_key=5500a486d12044849fe8ada1061c4d83&limit=5')
.then(res => res.json()).then((resp) => {

  // Here I changed 'data' to 'resp' and am accessing the data array.
  this.setState({images:resp.data});

})
```

Comment: wow , thanks Stephen , you are right , but y i cant use .then((res)=> ) and res.data ?

Comment: You could name `resp` to whatever you'd like. I just changed it to make it a little clearer

Comment: What if .. I try to get the data in data/ images /Original/url what should I set for the props?

Comment: Sorry, had to sleep after I answered this. You should run through this tutorial for functional programming. http://reactivex.io/learnrx/ You will learn a lot about how to easily manipulate data to fit your needs. Netflix actually has their new hires run through that tutorial.